# Don't include tableViewFooter in UITableView contentSize?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, footer

I've attached a shadow to the bottom of my `UITableView`, via the `tableViewFooter` property. Works fine, looks great. Problem is, once the table is large enough to require scrolling, if I scroll to the bottom, that footer view is included in the scroll.

I'd prefer to see the shadow, but not have it included in the content size of the table, so that if I scroll to the bottom, the bottom of the last cell is at the bottom end, as opposed to the bottom of this footer.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the solution was to set a `contentInset` on the bottom of the `UITableView`. Easy peasy.